# First element of double pointer array is always "garbage"

Tags: c, pointers, double-pointer

when using qsort() to try and organize an array of pointers I always get garbage on the first element of the double pointer. I have a suspicion that it's pointing to the wrong memory address and I'm just not understanding.

I'm pretty pretty new to C (about 3-4 weeks) and if someone could help me understand why I'm getting the bad value and suggest how I could get around the problem I would appreciate it.

## code:

```c
    char *token;
    char **string_array = calloc(wordcount, sizeof(char));
    if (!string_array){
        fprintf(stderr, "couldn't make double pointer\n");
    }
    size_t str_array = 0;

    token = strtok(w2->data, "\n\t ");
    printf("token %ld: %s\n",str_array, token);
    size_t tok_len = strlen(token);
    string_array[str_array] = calloc(tok_len,sizeof(char));
    if (!string_array[str_array]){
        fprintf(stderr, "could not find any of your words\n");
        return;
    }
    if (!strncpy(string_array[str_array++], token, tok_len)){
        return;
    }
    
    for (int x = 1; x<wordcount; x++){
        token = strtok(NULL, "\n\t ");
        tok_len = strlen(token);
        string_array[str_array] = calloc(tok_len,sizeof(char));
        if (!string_array[str_array]){
            fprintf(stderr, "failed somewhere with other tokens\n");
            return;
        }
        printf("token %ld: %s\n",str_array, token);
        if (!strncpy(string_array[str_array++], token, tok_len)){
            puts("could not find one of your words\n");
            return;
        }
    }
    qsort(string_array, str_array, sizeof(*string_array), lexsort);

    for (int x = 0; x<wordcount; x++){
        printf("%s\n",string_array[x]);
    }
    return;
}
```

## the output of the program looks like:

```
**//shows me what flags the user has set**
a selected
this is the most recent character: a

**//debugging though print statements**
The struct was made
gathering words
Allocated space

** //lines of words read in from file passed on the command line**
token 0: is
token 1: a
token 2: file
token 3: of          
token 4: 123:LK
token 5: words
token 6: 123456789

**//output after the array has been sorted**
123456789
123:LK
        **//this blank spot is the first element of the array and sometimes it's random garbage from memory (depending on the word)**
a                    
file
of
words
```

## Already tried:

I thought if I expanded the double pointer array +1 *(calloc((wordcount + 1), sizeof(char))* and started added the elements at the first index of the array instead of the zeroth index *(str_array = 1;)* it might help but it just seg faults (naturally...)

Comment: I cannot run your code, so I wrote my answer based on just reading your code. If you want, you can post your complete code somewhere, so I can run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, double pointers are pointers that point to pointers, so in the `calloc` you must use `char *` instead of `char` and you should remember to initialize inner pointers too, which you actually did here `string_array[str_array] = calloc(tok_len,sizeof(char));`.

Second, strings in C are null terminated which means C stores `Hello` as `H e l l o NULL` so when you have `strlen` equals to 5 you need an array of 6 elements to store it.

```c
string_array[str_array] = calloc(tok_len,sizeof(char) + 1);
```

The following line in your code is correct:

```c
if (!strncpy(string_array[str_array++], token, tok_len)){
        return;
    }
```

but it is better to write it as to make more readable:

```c
if (!strncpy(string_array[str_array], token, tok_len)){
        return;
    }
str_array++;
```

About the `qsort`, I think it is correct and will work as expected. Again, using `sizeof(char *)` is more readable than `sizeof(*string_array)`.

Comment: this worked like a charm! thank you for your speedy response and explanation, now that I see the answer it couldn't be more obvious!